# Spring MVC: correct exception handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I am wondering how to bind exception `handling method` to `url mapping` method:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String users(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("userList", userDao.getAll());
        String[] b = new String[0];
        String a = b[1];
        return "user";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String handleAllException(Exception ex, @ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Exception happened");
        return "error_screen";
    }
}
```

I intentionally provoke `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in `users` method. But I see that `handleAllException` method wasn't executed.

**Question:**
What have I forgotten to get done to make `Exception Handling` work appropriately?

Comment: I think that you try to use annotation `@ModelAttribute` incorrectly. Please try something like that: 
` @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ModelAndView handleError(Exception exception) { 
   //Code here
  return new ModelAndView("error");
}`

Comment: Thank you, @NguaCon! This is correct and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do somedthing like this:

```
 @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
 public ModelAndView handleAllException(Exception ex) {
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("error_screen");
  model.addAttribute("error", "Exception happened");
  return model;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) -> @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
```

Comment: This array declaration is not necessary, its needed only when we have more that one exception class

Answer (score 0):

The reason is it has failed with the below exception while trying to invoke the handleAllException() method:

DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] --- **ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver: Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public java.lang.String controllers.handleAllException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)**
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable resolver for argument [1] [type=org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
HandlerMethod details:

Change the Method as below:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String handleAllException(Exception ex) {
        // model.addAttribute("error", String.format("Exception happened"));
        return "error_screen";
    }
```